# disappears in page refresh and closing the browser- webstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

- I am using web storage
- but when I refresh the page I don't see the submitted values in the browser...
- do you know why...
- providing my code below

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPBQxX

```
 $('.stored').keyup(function() {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });
```

Comment: This code calls `localStorage.clear()` on submitting. The values are saved **until** they are submitted

Comment: @PaulS. can you update in my codepen...its confusing :(

Comment: @PaulS. but after removing this line and when I do page refresh all the values in left side get dissappears

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing LocalStorage after each submission at the end of the onSubmit callback. Maybe clear the form values instead of clearing the Storage.

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var message = $('#message').val();
  var div = "<div><span>" + name + "</span><span >" + email + "</span><span>" + message + "</span><input type='button' value='Edit' name='editHistory'><input type='button' value='Delete' name='deleteHistory'></div>"; //add your data in span, p, input.. 
  //alert(div);

  $('.gettingValues').append(div); //apendd the div
  $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form 
  localStorage.clear(); >>>>>>>>>> RESETTING HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
});
```

Comment: but after removing this line and when I do page refresh all the values in left side get dissappears